# best way to Create excel object in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-interop

Can anyone please explain is there any difference between creating excel application like below code

```
 Dim xl As New Excel.Application
```

and

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
xl = New Excel.Application
```

Comment: There is no difference.  Since you only ever create one instance of Application, As New is not dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between these two methods.   Both lines of code produce the same IL in .NET.